# Deleting rows in excel based on characters

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently running a code in-order to delete a row if a specific character from a data set is read. The code I have running deletes only one character at the moment, how would I adjust this could to delete multiple characters that are in different calls within that column. Example under column A you have Bob in cell A1 and Sally in A23.

To add, at times Bob is followed by Bob21234 or Bob12434 so the numbers vary, how would I adjust the code delete all Bobs which are followed by a number?

```
Sub DeleteRows()
    Dim c As Range
    Dim SrchRng

    Set SrchRng = ActiveSheet.Range("A1", ActiveSheet.Range("A65536").End(xlUp))
    Do
        Set c = SrchRng.Find("Bob", LookIn:=xlValues)
        If Not c Is Nothing Then c.EntireRow.Delete
    Loop While Not c Is Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: you'd get it to find each bob regardless of numbers by adding to your search line: `Set c = SrchRng.Find("Bob", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)`

Comment: searching for multiple terms while avoiding exceptions would probably require you to use a different approach than `Range.Find()`

Comment: You are using a Find. You can instead loop the rows and do an IF evaluation: If Cells(i, 1).Value Like "Bob*" Then Cells.(i, 1).EntireRow.Delete if there is thousands of rows you want to disable screenupdating and set calculation to Manual before and revert it back when the loop is done. Tip: When deleting Rows start your loop backwards, from last row to first.

Comment: Could you possibly share a code with it corrected? Still fairly new to VBA and I am still learning.

Comment: Why don't you just delete all rows which contain a number in Column A?  Also, please use `ActiveSheet.Range("A1",ActiveSheet.Range("A" & ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp)`

Comment: What should it do if you have the names "Rob" and "Robert"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options. You could try them both, I'm not sure which one is faster. The first one would allow you to change it to add exceptions which may make it better for you.

This one will manually check line-by-line for the terms you include in the `if` statement.

```
Sub Option1()

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim current As String

    For i = 65536 To 1 Step -1
        current = LCase$(ActiveSheet.Range("A" & i).Value2)

        If InStr(current, "bob") > 0 Then ActiveSheet.Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
        If InStr(current, "sue") > 0 And InStr(current, "sally") = 0 Then ActiveSheet.Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
    Next i

End Sub
```

This one uses the built in `Range.Find()` method, so it might be better optimized than just a regular loop. However, you have to call it again for each term you want to find.

```
Sub Option2()

    Call DeleteRows(ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A65536"), "Bob", "")
    Call DeleteRows(ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A65536"), "Sue", "Sally")

End Sub

Sub DeleteRows(ByVal rng As Range, ByVal term As String, ByVal exception As String)

    Dim c As Range
    Do
        Set c = rng.Find(What:=term, After:=Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
        If Not c Is Nothing Then
            If InStr(LCase$(c.Value2), LCase$(exception)) = 0 Then c.EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Loop While Not c Is Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: So the second one worked well, what if I wanted to make one of the Call DeleteRows(ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A65536"), "Sue") case senstive, so if Sue and Sally followed after it did not delete unless it specifically said Sue and Sally

Comment: That's not what case sensitive means. However, to do what you're asking you'd change it from "Sue" to "Sue and Sally"

Comment: Let me clarify. I want the current code to just eliminate Sue but when Sue and Sally occurs I don't want it to eliminate that. Currently when I am running the code, it is eliminating any row with Sue.

Comment: I only require that simple change and the solution is perfect

Comment: @WaleedMalik I don't know that there is a simple way to make that work with the second option. However, I made that change in the first option - let me know how it works for you.

Comment: The update did not work for me. It still deletes Sue and Sally

Comment: @WaleedMalik Okay I think that now both options should be viable

Comment: If Not c Is Nothing And Not InStr(c.Value2, exception) Then c.EntireRow.Delete

This line is giving me an error for Solution 2

Comment: @Marcucciboy2, or you could use my method of adding it to a Range Variable to delete once at the end (which is faster, less flicker if screen updating isn't turned off and less prone to error).

Comment: @WaleedMalik then why did you mark it as the answer?  BTW `InStr` returns an `integer` value of the position where the text is found, not true/false.  Might want to change it to `If InStr(...)=0 then`

Comment: @WaleedMalik what is the issue / error it is giving you?

Comment: @Profex Waleed is welcome to use your solution if they would like to. Also, `InStr` still evaluates correctly checking it as a boolean.

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 how is that?...`?cbool(Not 0)` = True, `?cbool(Not 2)` = True,

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 you missed the `Not`...which makes all the difference in the world.  `Not 0 = -1` and `Not 2 = -3`...and since `0 = False` and `Any Number other then 0 = True` we end up with a logical error.

Answer (score 0):

For Loop approach with Like comparison (instead of Like you can use InStr).

```
Sub DeleteRows()
    Dim SrchRng as Long
    Dim i As Long
    Set SrchRng = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    For i = SrchRng to 1 Step -1
        If ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value Like "Bob*" Or ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value Like "Mark*" Then Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Delete
    Next i
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Please stop with the hard coded names!  That's the hardest part of the problem.

Comment: @Profex if you don't like an answer you can down vote it using the arrows to the left.

Answer (score 0):

Do you require VBA for this? or would you like an Excel Formula solution?

Simply add a column with the formula `=COUNTIF(A:A,A1&"*")` and then filter the list and delete any value that is `>1`.

---

But please answer the question: 
What should it do if you have the names "Rob" and "Robert"?

---

It's probably just easier to remove names with numbers in them, if so, then this is all you need:

```
Sub DeleteValuesWithNumbers(Target As Range)
Dim Cell As Range, DeleteRange As Range
    For Each Cell In Target
        If Cell Like "*[0-9]*" Then Set DeleteRange = MakeUnion(DeleteRange, Cell)
    Next
    If Not DeleteRange Is Nothing Then DeleteRange.EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```

Extra Function to make the Range Union() cleaner:

```
Public Function MakeUnion(Arg1 As Range, Arg2 As Range) As Range
    If Arg1 Is Nothing Then
        Set MakeUnion = Arg2
    ElseIf Arg2 Is Nothing Then
        Set MakeUnion = Arg1
    Else
        Set MakeUnion = Union(Arg1, Arg2)
    End If
End Function
```